# How can I compare the similarity between multiple sets?

Tags: comparison, data-analysis, data-mining, similarity, set-intersection

Imagine I have hundreds sellers who have a set of customer ids and I count how many customers they share (the similarity of these sets). I need to look at the similarity between multiple sets and find a suitable method to calculate some coefficient to help me find the greatest similarity.

So I created pairs of sellers and calculated the Jaccard similarity coefficient for each pair.

The problem is if I want to extend this to triples, quadruples, and so on...

How can I compare the similarity between multiple sets?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.